# Flutter NotificationCenter Observer

Tags: dart, observable, flutter

Coming from Xcode I was wondering if there is anything similar to NotificationCenter Observer in Flutter.
I have seen that there is this package called Observable which I am not able to install.

Because your_app depends on observable `^0.22.1+1` which depends on
quiver `>=0.24.0 <0.29.0`, quiver `>=0.24.0 <0.29.0` is required.

I have also added quiver as a package but it remains the same. Also, it would be very helpful once I got this Observable working to get a simple example because I can't find any good documentation on that.

Also seen RXDart but also he there is no simple example.

Comment: Can you please provide a link or add an explanation what "Coming from Xcode I was wondering if there is anything similar to NotificationCenter Observer" means? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Fair enough. Let's assume the app receives a push notification with data. I want to obverse this event and show a snackbar appearing to inform the user about it. Or I want to observe if a certain screen is visible in order to update information or nor depending on that.

Comment: You don't need any package for that.  A snopped from my project: `_firebaseMessaging
      ..configure(
        onMessage: (message) {
          // do nothing
        },
        onLaunch: _selectGroup,
        onResume: _selectGroup,
      )
      ..requestNotificationPermissions(
          const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _subscriptions
        .add(_firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((settings) {}));`

Comment: You can just use streams which are part of Dart (from `dart:async`). RxDart builds upon these streams with additional features.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. Would appreciate any simple example you could provide on using streams.

Comment: Would be easier wit a more concrete question.

Comment: How could I create a stream in onMessage in order to assign the data message to that stream. Then in another class I would like to listen/subscribe to that stream in order to action if a message comes in.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/creating-streams

Comment: Maybe I need to get my head around this a bit more but as newbie I find this hard to understand. Thanks for the link anyways. I don't see any way to assign message to a stream. What typ of stream would match Map<String, dynamic>?

Comment: `Stream<Map<String, dynamic>>` or perhaps if you want one event per string-value pair, you can create a `Message` class with a key and value property and use `Stream<Message>`

Comment: Done that both ways but how to add message to that stream?

Comment: Have solved it with using StreamController which creates a Stream according to my requirements. I subscribe in the view I need then to that Broadcast via StreamSubscription. Thanks